# Show a div if i hover hyperlink

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If i hover the .header_kosar_link, the .cart_hover div will be displayed. Now, it will be displayed by jquery, with the code below.

How can i make the div showned, when i move the cursor into it?

```css
.cart_hover{ max-width:300px; display:none;  background:#fff; position:absolute; right:0; top:60px; z-index:999; padding:15px; border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 16px rgba(50, 56, 77, 0.35);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end align-items-center header_div">
  <a href="https://projektar.hu/kosar" title="Kosár" class="header_kosar_link d-flex align-items-center">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fejlec_kosar_ikon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span id="header_kosar_text" class="header_kosar_text">Cart</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="cart_hover">Cart Hover</div>


<script>
  $('.header_kosar_link').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.cart_hover').css('display', 'block');
  });
  $('.header_kosar_link').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.cart_hover').css('display', 'none');
  });
</script>
```

The .cart_hover div has this css:

```
.cart_hover{ max-width:300px; display:none;  background:#fff; position:absolute; right:0; top:60px; z-index:999; padding:15px; border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 16px rgba(50, 56, 77, 0.35);
```

Comment: where jquery's `document.ready()` ?

Comment: Its in the file, the hover is working.

Comment: What is the issue here, do you want to have the solution in CSS instead of javascript?

Comment: Pls check the demo site at projektar.hu. Put some products in the cart, and then hover the cart ikon at the right side in the header. The hover isnt working with this code: .header_kosar_link:hover > .cart_hover {visibility: visible;}

Comment: @Tibi458, I added my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this easily by CSS. No need for javascript/JQuery. Just add a `:hover` selector on the parent element. I would also advice to use `visibility` instead of `display`.

```
.flex-container:hover > .cart_hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container > .d-flex {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flex-container > .cart_hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}


.flex-container:hover > .cart_hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end align-items-center header_div">
    <a href="https://projektar.hu/kosar" title="Kosár" class="header_kosar_link d-flex align-items-center">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fejlec_kosar_ikon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span id="header_kosar_text" class="header_kosar_text"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="cart_hover">CART</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this snippet, its working, but on my site, with this code, it does nothing. .header_kosar_link:hover > .cart_hover {
  visibility: visible;
}

Comment: And i only want this, when i hover the .header_kosar_link

Comment: @Tibi458 that is not possible using pure CSS, not with the HTML structure you currently have. CSS can not select “upwards” in the DOM tree, which would be necessary here though.

Comment: And, if i just simply write a hover code to the .header_kosar_link, it does nothing. Like change the font color on hover, nothing works.

Comment: OK, I read in a sloppy way. Anyways, you can't hover a `display: none` element because it has a height of 0. You should use `visibility´ or `opacity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using combination of [~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) and [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), note that I added class `cart-container`, notice that my selector is on the parent of the `<a>` tag:

```css
.cart-container:hover ~ div:nth-of-type(3) {
  visibility: visibile;
  display: block;
}

.cart_hover {
 max-width: 300px;
 display: none;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 60px;
 z-index: 999;
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 16px rgba(50, 56, 77, 0.35);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end align-items-center header_div cart-container">
  <a href="https://projektar.hu/kosar" title="Kosár" class="header_kosar_link d-flex align-items-center">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fejlec_kosar_ikon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span id="header_kosar_text" class="header_kosar_text">Cart</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="cart_hover">Cart Hover</div>
```